# Java Jar files closing after running for 3 seconds

Tags: java, jar, launcher

So I created a game launcher that successfully downloads a Zip and extracts it. But then it tries opening the Jar file that was in the zip, and all that happens is the game pops up for about 2 seconds then closes. If I manually double click it it works fine, or if I run it through the command line, it works fine... Here are the two snippets of code I've tried using to get the Jar running. (Take note the jar does not return any errors on run):

```
Runtime rt =Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("java -jar \""+appdata+"\\gamefiles\\Game.jar\"");
```

and...

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-jar", appdata+"/gamefiles/Game.jar").start();
int result = proc.waitFor();
System.out.println(result);
```

Any feedback is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any errors on output? Do you actually have a main specified in the Manifest for your jar file you are trying to run?

Comment: No errors on output. And yes the jar was compiled with the required libraries using Jarsplice, and I used the correct path for the main class.

Comment: You're not reading the process's  stdout, so how do you know there's no error?

Comment: I run on command prompt and i dont get an error. I also run in eclipse so it tells me if theres an error during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a process builder, and you don't specify anything about the environment, is there a chance that your JAR file can't find needed elements (like JVM location or classpath) because it's not getting an environmental variable?

Comment: well using "java.exe -jar %appdata%/gamesfiles/Game.jar" works fine in the command prompt so I do have my environmental variables set properly.

Comment: I'd expect environmental variables to work just fine in the command prompt.  I'd question whether they work "just fine" in the ProcessBuilder class.  If it works when your java code `appdata` is `%appdata%` then you're probably ok.  Either way, there are probably openGL libraries that you Java stuff is not finding, and there is a chance it has to do with them not being defined / handled the same from the ProcessBuilder point of view.

Comment: I use this to find the appdata variable in java "String appdata = System.getenv("APPDATA");" and if the jar file runs when i double click it then it loads the dependencies correctly I thought. Thats why I'm confused, if it can run stand-alone why wont it run through the java code.

Comment: Perhaps `APPDATA` is not the only environmental variable that's important?  I can easily imagine `PATH`, `JAVA_HOME`, and any OpenGL Java specific environmental variables as possibly having an impact on the java command.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Why? The environment used by Java should be the same used by the os. Sure, you can override them using the ProcessBuilder but I'm unaware of a circumstance where they would be different by default

Comment: If you think you're going to solve your problem by arguing with me, you're just going to waste both of our time.  I asked if you checked it, and if you did, you'll either know it's an issue or it's not an issue.  In which case, you'll be one step closer to having the answer.  What I say isn't gospel, the proof is in what you verified with your own eyes on your own machine.  Perhaps it is an issue, and if I were you, I'd spend a little time to make sure it wasn't.  _I doubt that ProcessBuilder launches its own shell, so I'd guess it handles environment differently than the shell._

Comment: Alright thanks for your help. That other comment wasnt by me by the way... That was some random. Anyways I really appriciate your help and ill read up more on the ProcessBuilder class. Thanks, James.

Comment: @Frostsoft You're welcome, and no worries.  Thanks for pointing out the comment came from someone else.  I tend to sometimes overlook that the person "speaking to me" changes occasionally in these message threads.  Good luck!